# Rotating Displays and docked laptop

Tags: settings

I am running into an issue with rotating a display. I am running a docked dell laptop and using two external displays. After boot when it goes to the login screen it displays only on my laptop display which I am not using unless I am out of the office. The secondary issue I am having is  22 inch display that is rotated vertically for viewing code, programming, etc. When I go into settings and set the screen to rotate and hit apply nothing happens. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question to include the model numbers of laptop, video device, and monitors, along with the video driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Which graphics card is in the laptop?

Nvidia, intel or amd. The answer to what to do depends on that

you can use lspci | grep VGA to find the model of the card you are currently using.

You can screenshot a reply to me or write which one it is, depending on that I'll lik you to the right driver and how to install it

Comment: Dell Latitude-E5430-vPro 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: Can you try updating your intel graphics driver using the tool intel has provided on their website, and then try it again and tell me the result

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2

Comment: It says the distro is not supported Checking if Intel graphics card available...
  • checking for i915 module in /sys/module
  • i915 module found
Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org...
  • fetching https://download.01.org/gfx/ilg-config.cfg
  • saving to /home/jacob/.ilg-config
  • fetched 1626 bytes
  • fetched 9818 bytes
  • fetched 12301 bytes
  • looking up [elementary loki] configuration
Retrieving information from 01.org... OK
Checking distribution... Failed